# Break up HTML attribute values into multiple lines

Tags: html, syntax, attributes, escaping, html-escape-characters

Is there a way to format HTML attribute values so they span across multiple lines?
Essentially I'm asking is there a way to escape a return inside of a regular typed HTML attribute value.

For example in this *working* code below we have the `href` attribute value on one single line.

```html
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  > <!-- href value above spans 1 line and wraps normally with text editors width -->
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bootstrap has successfully applied because this font is sans-serif</h1>
</body>
```

how could I get this *unworking* code in this format with the attribute value spanning **multiple** lines below to work?:

```html
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link
    rel="stylesheet" 
    href= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/
           bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/
           bootstrap.min.css"
  > <!-- href value above spans 3 lines -->
</head>
<body>
  <h1>
    Bootstrap hasn't applied due to the amount of 
    <mark>enter</mark> characters used in the <mark>href</mark> attribute
  </h1>
</body>
```

It seems that as soon as when you add returns into a value the whole value fails. I've tried regular javaScript escape characters but with no luck.

### How can I successfully add returns *( new lines )* in HTML attribute values?

Comment: I think from specification point of view you can add new lines in html attributes, but they are not recognized by the `link` `script` or other tags in your browser

Comment: @ashishmaurya so this would work on a different tag? Perhaps a class name on a `h1` tag?

Comment: Yes, Just don't break your class name(otherwise CSS will not work)

Comment: @ashishmaurya breaking up class name or any attribute is what i'm asking. I tried it and yeah it doesn't appear to work: https://jsfiddle.net/tegqL4br/. Is there any example I could make to test this on other attributes/tags ?

Comment: I don't believe HTML attributes have a line continue construct.

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible with current HTML implementation in browser. As for `new line support in attribute`  its accepted in all attributes but its treated differently. As you can see in this https://jsfiddle.net/tgy7remd/ new line is retained

Comment: @ashishmaurya interesting. Did you mean to link to a copy of my original fiddle? It still doesn't appear to work there the `<h1>` text is not purple in my browser ( chrome ).

Comment: Even if it trimmed the newlines out, I would expect it to replace it with a single space, so something like `class='make-the- text-purple'` (there also is, actually, spaces in the attribute, not just newlines). The browser is told there's whitespace to consider, so it does, even if it treats some of it special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe HTML attributes have an "attribute" continue construct like line continues in Javascript or command lines.

So this doesn't really work:

```
// This is just whitespace, so I assume the browser will encode it
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/
      bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/
      bootstrap.min.css"

// Javascript variety
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/" +
     "bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/" +
     "bootstrap.min.css"

// Command line variety
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/" \
     "bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/" \
     "bootstrap.min.css"
```

It's just whitespace within the attribute, or quoted strings untethered to an attribute like in the above examples.

This is the best I could come up with:

```
<script>
let link = document.createElement('link')

link.rel = 'stylesheet'
link.href = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/' +
            'npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/' +
            'dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

document.head.append(link)
</script>
```

You *may* be able to do some Tidying to find and remove the unnecessary whitespace in certain tag attributes. If the point is to format the browser's View Source markup for readability, though, it would defeat that purpose.

Comment: Yeah it looks like JavaScript is the only possible route here. Thanks: https://jsfiddle.net/v653tuns/

Answer (score -1):

Can you please break down your question please! I’m having hard time to understand but if you are asking about formatting the code I would use a code editor and see if their is a feature for formatting the code. In vs code their is an feature for formatting the code. But I am not sure if you have! Sorry, if you didn’t got what you have said but that’s nice to ask question. Keep it up!!!

Comment: I'm not asking about how a text editor formats your code. I'm asking if I can use the `enter` key inside of attribute values using some technique like escape characters.